# Unable to debug typescript project with node:worker_threads, cannot find module error

Tags: node.js, node-worker-threads

I have a typescript project which uses node:worker_threads. However, when I try to debug individual ts files, I keep getting error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node:worker_threads'
```

It should be noted that the problem shouldn't be in the node version, I am running node 16.19.0 and have

```
"engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  }
```

in my package.json. Any other idea what might have gone wrong? I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2, uninstalled node via apt and set it up by nvm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was some weird conflict after all. In the end, the only solution that helped was to completely uninstall node, clean up leftover files and install it again.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to update to Node 18, as it's the current LTS.  Most recent node updates tend not to have many breaking changes, but rather new features so it's usually painless.  Also you only have until 11 Sep 2023 for security fixes for 16.  I've noticed Linux package manager are often behind in updates, if that's how you install node, if so I would  recommend you use something like nvm. https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: Oh, BTW.  That other question you deleted about splitting text into 3 parts,  start/middle/end,  this might help ->  `'firstPart second part which will be one string lastPart'.match(/^(.*?(?= )) (.*) (.*$)/).slice(1)`